# How to assign a value to a matrix created with assign() in R

Tags: r, assign

```
m <- "mData"
assign(m, matrix(data = NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 5))
```

Now I want to use variable m to assign values to the mData matrix

`assign(m[1, 2], 35)` will not work.

Any solution will be much appreciated?

Comment: Why not skip the middle man and go straight to `m <- matrix(, 4, 5); m[1,2] <- 35`.  `assign()` is a function that really should not be used very much.

Comment: There is also a loop enclosing these lines. So m is changing with every loops. The values to be assigned in each loop are also different. The result will be a number of matrix with different names.

Comment: This is really going at it the wrong way round but you could gather the names into vector and create a list of matrices with `mget`. Then apply an appropriate function to them with `lapply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm kind of ashamed to post this but there would be a way to do this. It feels so wrong because the R-way would be to build a list of matrices and then operate on them by passing a function to transform them using lapply.

```
assign.by.char <- function(x,  ...) {
   eval.parent(assign(x,  do.call(`[<-`, list(get(x) , ...)))) }

assign.by.char(m, 1,2,35)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA   35   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: It is really me who feel ashamed. Your codes works well. Thank you! But I do not quite understand both 'eval.parent()' and '[<-'. What values do we need from parent environment? What does '[<-' do?

Comment: `[<-( arg1, arg2,arg3,arg4)` is the same as `arg1[arg2,arg3] <- arg4` except it is written in functional form.  `eval.parent` specifies that the evaluation of arguments will be occurring in calling environment. It's the mechanism for getting the assignment to stick in an environment that would normally not be touched inside a function body. Doing it this way makes it look like the function is working via side-effects. That's the part that's considered morally suspect. Most of R is done with functions that return a value that then gets assigned to an R name.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use `assign()`, you could do it with `replace()`

```
m <- matrix(, 3, 3)
assign("m", replace(m, cbind(1, 2), 35))
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   35   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `assign` directly (a variant of @BondedDust's solution)

```
 assign(m, `[<-`(get(m), cbind(1,2), 35))
 mData
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 #[1,]   NA   35   NA
 #[2,]   NA   NA   NA
 #[3,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Or as a function

```
assign.by.char <- function(x, ...){
  eval.parent(assign(x, `[<-`(get(x), ...)))}
```

#### data

```
mData <- matrix(, 3, 3)
 m <- 'mData'
```